# Can cover art be stored in the METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE field of a Vorbis Comment tag using TagLib#?

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp, vorbis, oggvorbis

Can cover art be stored in the METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE field of a Vorbis Comment tag on an Ogg Vorbis file using TagLib#?

Answer (score 0):

The following will work but requires that a private property ("LastPageHeader") of the Ogg Vorbis file object be read using reflection:

```
TagLib.Ogg.File oggFile = (TagLib.Ogg.File)TagLib.File.Create(@"C:\music.ogg");

PropertyInfo headerProp = oggFile.GetType()
                                 .GetProperty("LastPageHeader", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
TagLib.Ogg.PageHeader header = (TagLib.Ogg.PageHeader)headerProp.GetValue(oggFile);

TagLib.Flac.Picture pic = new TagLib.Flac.Picture(new TagLib.Flac.Picture(@"C:\img.jpeg"));
TagLib.ByteVector picData = pic.Render();

TagLib.Ogg.GroupedComment groupedCommentTag = (TagLib.Ogg.GroupedComment)oggFile.Tag;

TagLib.Ogg.XiphComment xiphComment = groupedCommentTag.GetComment(header.StreamSerialNumber);
xiphComment.SetField("METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE", Convert.ToBase64String(picData.Data));

oggFile.Save();
```